# react-select component options are not applied

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to give options props programmingly, but options do not appear.

I'm getting data from graphql server by using react-apollo-hooks, and try to give some data to options of react-select.
I checked data and they were fine. However, using data doesn't work (Select component shows "No Options"), while declaring array works.

I checked that I properly passed variables between files, and received right data.

Here's my code:

## Conatiner.js

```
const generated_list = [];
const listGenerator = () => {
  data.sample.map( single => {
    const temp = { label: single.A, value: single.B };
    generated_list.push(temp);
  }
}
```

where data is

```
data.sample = [ { A: '1', B: '1', C: '1' }, { A: '2', B: '2', C: '2' } ]
```

## Presenter.js

```
<Button onClick={() => listGenerator()} text={'Get Lists'} />
<Select options={generated_list} />
```

But following code worked as I expect.

```
const declared_list = { [label: '1', value: '1'], 
               [label: '2', value: '2'] };
...
<Button onClick={() => listGenerator()} text={'Get Lists'} />
<Select options={declared_list} />
```

I thought generated list differs from declared list, so I compared them by console log.

```
console.log(
  typeof generated_list,
  generated_list`,
  JSON.stringify(generated_list),
  typeof declared_list,
  declared_list`,
  JSON.stringify(declared_list),
  JSON.stringify(generated_list) === JSON.stringify(declared_list),
);
```

All things were same, and `===` operator returned true.

I don't know what to check next, so any helps would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: show your full container js file

Comment: i think your generated_list[] does not rerender the component after pushed all arrays. use setState instead.

Comment: Can you check if generated_list array has data only then call select component. In your case generated_list is empty when select is trying to render Therefore the check.

Comment: Instead of      generated_list.push(temp); , can you try  generated_list = [...generated_list, temp]? or if that doesnt work, trying slicing?  I feel, react will update its UI only when there is a change (in your code, the reference still stays same and so its not updating).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Sathish Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722893/react-select-component-options-are-not-applied#comment98125726_55722893) in the comments, changes on the array do not affect React to trigger a rerender of the component.

You should move the array into the state and update the array using `this.setState` (or if you are using a functional component, use Reacts new [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)).

```
class MySelect extends Component {
   state = {
      options: [],
   }

   populateArray = () => {
       var newOptions = [];

       /* Populate the `newOptions` array */

       this.setState({ options: newOptions });
   }

   render() {
       return (<>
           <Button onClick={this.populateArray}>Click me</Button>
           <Select { ... } options={this.state.options} />
       <>);
   }
}
```